# Accessing instance variables withing ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Been following Rails Testing Prescriptions. The `Task` table has a column named `completed_at`. Why can I only write to it with `self.completed_at = date` (`completed_at = date` fails) but I can access the attribute without `self` in the `complete?` method?

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :project

  def mark_completed(date = Time.current)
    self.completed_at = date
  end

  def complete?
    completed_at.present?
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: These are not instance variables, btw.

Comment: Because local variables take precedence over instance methods.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the input!